# Usage of 'allocate'

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

If I qualify a test conducted for various departments and I'm selected in, say, administrative group, what would be the right way to say it?

> 1. I've been **allocated** to administrative group.
> 2. I've got **allocation** in administrative group.

Is the usage of allocated/allocation correct? Also, please share alternative ways to say the same thing.
I'm asking this because English is not my first language, I'm still a learner. I've realised that most of the sentences that the people of my area write or speak are not idiomatic to native speakers, which is why I now try to confirm whenever I come across sentences I'm unsure of.

Comment: I made your post more specific based on your title. Otherwise, it looks like "proofreading", which is off-topic here. If you can [edit] your post and add more details (e.g. explain why you are concerned), that would be better. See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for more tips and examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first way: "I've been allocated" is better.

Unless you are treating the word "administration group" as a proper noun, you should use an article "... the administration group".

There are many other possible expressions:

> My allocation is in the admin group.
>
> They've allocated me to Administration.
>
> I'm going to be an administrator.